# Trying to search for specific value within text file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to search for a specific value within an array of files. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but some insight would be great.

I've tried containing all lines from each file into an array that can be read from within an `if statement`.

```
    void getAssetTag()
    {
        string path = @"\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);//Grabbing Directory
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files

        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            string[] asset = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);

            if (asset.Contains(AssetT.Text) == true) {

                string allinfo = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                Results.Text = allinfo;
            }

        }
    }
```

The results should output the entire data from the text file contained within `AssetT.Text`into `Results.Text`.

Comment: `asset.Contains(AssetT.Text)` does a full line comparison. You will miss any lines that contain the match plus other text. Also, you miss lines that wrap. Why not just read the entire file and check that? See: [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8) (though you will have to strip newlines from that to get wrapped matches.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asset` is a `string[]`, where each string is a line of text. When you do `if (asset.Contains(AssetT.Text))`, you're comparing an ***entire line*** to `AssetT.Text`.

If you want to find out if any single line contains `AssetT.Text`, then we need to call `Contains` on the ***line***, not the ***array***:

```
if (asset.Any(line => line.Contains(AssetT.Text))
```

Also, you're ending up reading the file twice here, once when you do `ReadAllLines`, and again when you do `ReadAllText`. Since it seems you will always read the whole file (either to determine that the file doesn't contain the text, or to get all the contents because it *does* contain the text), you should just do it once.

If you use `File.ReadAllText` in the beginning, now we have a `string` representation of the entire file which we can call `.Contains` on:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
    string asset = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);

    if (asset.Contains(AssetT.Text))
    {
        Results.Text = asset;

        // No use reading more files unless we're going
        // to save the contents to another variable
        break; 
    }
}
```

Note that we `break` out of the loop since it appears you're setting the contents of the file to a single field of some class, so searching for more files will just overwrite any previous results found.

This can be simplified further using `System.Linq` extension methods and method chaining. We can also use `Directory.GetFiles` (which returns a list of file paths) instead, since we don't need a full-blown `FileInfo` object:

```
Results.Text = Directory
    .GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
    .Select(File.ReadAllText)
    .FirstOrDefault(fileText => fileText.Contains(AssetT.Text)) ?? Results.Text;
```

Comment: I modified the statement as described, but it is not producing the results needed. Once the condition of that statement is true it shouldn't loop again and should hold onto whatever file was part of the iteration that found the tag correct?

Comment: The `Results.Text` property should contain the contents of the first file that has a line containing `AssetT.Text`

Comment: Just noticed your edit. I will get back with you after modifications.

Comment: After modifying the code, I am still running into the issue of it not producing `string asset = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);`

This is the layout of the line I am trying to read by just inputting the numbers.
Asset Tag: 0000. 

Should `Contains` see 0000 and know that is the file it needs? Or would it need Asset Tag: 0000

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. `Contains` will look for whatever string you pass to it, and return `true` if the calling string contains it. For example, `"Asset Tag: 0000".Contains("0000")` will return `true`, and `"0000".Contains("Asset Tag: 0000")` will return `false`. But it's not clear what `AssetT.Text` is, nor what the file line you're trying to match looks like because there isn't any sample data in the question.

Comment: I apologize, this was an error with a prior method after looking further into it. Your code is correct. Thank you for the help!